# Degree of polynomial in polynomial approximation of continuous function on circle

Tags: real-analysis

We know that any (complex-valued) continuous function on the circle can be uniformly approximated by a polynomial. If I'm not mistaken, the degree of such a polynomial can be controlled by the modulus of continuity of the original function. This may be wishful thinking, but is there any way of controlling the degree of the polynomial by the sup norm of the original function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first statement is false.  To uniformly approximate continuous functions on the unit circle you need rational functions, not just polynomials.  For example, $1/z$ is continuous on the unit circle $\mathbb T$, and $\oint_{\mathbb T} (1/z)\; dz = 2 \pi i$, but $\oint_{\mathbb T} p(z)\; dz = 0$ for any polynomial $p$ by Cauchy's theorem.

In fact the functions that can be uniformly approximated by polynomials on the 
unit circle are those that can be extended to the closed unit disk in such a way that they are analytic in the open disk.  This is an infinite-dimensional Banach space $A$.

As for your question: no, there is no way to control the degree of the polynomial using the sup norm of the function.  In fact, for any positive integer $n$ we can take the function $f(z) = z^{n+1}$ which is in $A$ with $\|f\| = 1$.  If $p$ is a polynomial of degree $\le n$, 
note that 
$$ \dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{\mathbb T} z^{-n-2} (f(z) - p(z))\; dz = 1$$
while
$$ \left|\dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{\mathbb T} z^{-n-2} (f(z) - p(z))\; dz\right| \le \|f - p\|$$
so that $\|f - p\| \ge 1$.  Thus polynomials of degree $\le n$ don't help at all in approximating $z^{n+1}$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I might have been thinking of the circle as an interval.